# Issue with loading assets in Flutter using inappwebview package

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies, flutter-inappwebview

I am currently developing an app in Flutter which uses inappwebview to load HTML pages inside the application.
I am currently facing an issue where not all of the assets are loaded in when I run the app on my Android device, and I am not sure why.

[Chrome device inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdX6t.png)

**pubspec.yaml file**

```yaml
assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
     - DIBapp/bootstrap/index.html
     - DIBapp/bootstrap/
     - DIBapp/bootstrap/icons/
     - DIBapp/bootstrap/topics/APP/
     - DIBapp/bootstrap/topics/use/APP/
```

It is the "topics" folder which is not getting loaded. I use inappwebview to load in the index.html file as the initial file like so:

```
child: InAppWebView(initialFile:
                        "DIBapp/bootstrap/index.html",)
```

The result is that the hyperlinks in the loaded index.html file only show a blank space instead of the content specified in its HTML file.